# What chains are OK for a Brompton?

Tags: chain, drivetrain, brompton

What type of chain should I buy for my Brompton bicycle?

The chain on my Brompton bicycle is stretched, and I would like to buy a replacement. There is no Brompton dealer in my country, so I'd like to just go to a bike shop and purchase a new chain, but I'm not sure which chain I should ask for that will "fit" the brompton.

What type of chain should I buy to replace my brompton's old chain?

Comment: Please answer this question in general (for all Brompton models) so it can help *any* Brompton owner (not just me) determine which chain they can buy that will work for their bicycle.

Comment: The answer will almost certainly be along the lines of "count your sprockets" because Bromptons have been sold with several gear configurations including internally geared hubs

Comment: See also the Brompton "ds-chain" Data Sheet https://trade.brompton.com/Uploads/QPart/QPart-Datasheets/ds-chain.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Bromptons use 3/32" chain which is (or was) the standard derailleur chain, even if your Brompton doesn't have derailleur gears.

When buying a replacement chain, pick a 7/8 speed one. The 9-speed, 10-speed and 11-speed ones are too narrow.

However, pre-2011 Bromptons may use a different chain.

New Bromptons use the 3/32" chain for 3-speed systems too that only have internal gear hubs. So unlike all other bikes that have a different chain width for derailleur and non-derailleur systems, Bromptons always use the derailleur chain.